# Ubuntu recognises other partitions but does not show the contents

Tags: windows, ntfs

I hold up my hand to confess I'm an immigrant from Microsoft and I use the computer as a tool, not a hobby. Ubuntu (12.10) recognizes the partitions used for Windows, e.g. my docs but not it's contents. Can I ever save there? If not, can I copy Ubuntu files to Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal window and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

This will install a small program that lets you turn on a few things for your Windows NTFS partitions and enable you to write to them...  You will find the program in your application menu after install or in Unity by searching for NTFS.